# Please recommend a good technical design tool for iPad or OS X

Tags: macos, ipad, ios, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to create isometric and flattened designs. I'm looking for an application that allows designing of engineering projects for wood working.

I've spent a lot of money looking for an app but most are tools for sketching and artwork orientated.

Some features I'm really looking for are:

- Easy to use
- Isometric and flat views for same design to be shown
- Vector based design, allowing me to resize, move objects individually
- Measurement and scale support, allowing me to specify a scale and then size elements based on that scale (in metric notation)
- Layers support would be preferred to allow measurements to be supplied on a separate layer

I don't want an overly complex tool, I just want a nice tool to do the job of creating designs alleviating the need for me to use pencil and paper.

Comment: you should list the one you tested, the one you don't like, and the one you know that are close to want you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, check out [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/). I don't think its on iOS yet, but it is lovely in its simplicity, short learning curve and flexibility. There are tons of YouTube clips showing off features and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

`iDesk` seems to fit into your criteria. It is a cool iPad app that is more toward diagrams and vector graphics than sketching. It has a very nice interface, too. It has a killer feature that is when you draw a shape (circle, triangle,...) it recognizes it and changes it to the vector form.

Update: I recently found `iDraw` which blew me away with its abilities in vector graphics. Some even describe it as the illustrator on iOS. You might wanna give it a try.

iDraw: http://www.indeeo.com/idraw

iDesk: http://www.tentouchapps.com/idesk

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Flom Enol! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: Answer edited. Thanks @daviesgeek for mentioning to add the links.

Answer (score 0):

[Hexagon](http://www.daz3d.com/products/hexagon/hexagon-what-is-hexagon) from DAZ 3D works well for me, and is simple enough that after an hour I could do some fun things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Everett! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.daz3d.com/products/hexagon  Bad news is that it's free on Mac and Windows.  At least it was when I got it.

Comment: Can you edit that link and information into your post? Thanks!